# ¿ Por que mi ruta de laravel funciona de cierta manera y de otra no?

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Estoy comenzando a usar Laravel y a la hora de definir mis rutas, mi ruta '/' solo irve cuando la defino de esta manera:

```
Route::view('/', 'home')->name('home');
```

Pero si yo la defino de esta manera, laravel no la encuentra:

```
Route::view('/', function (){
    return view('home');
});
```

Mis archivos estan de la siguiente manera:
[image: Imagen de como mis archivos estan organizados]

El error que obtengo es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Esperas recibir algún parámetro por URL?, entonces [debes especificarlo](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-parameters). Si no esperas parámetros, no tiene sentido usar el segundo formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el nombre que le das a la ruta... no en como la definas.

Dentro del archivo `layout.blade.php` seguramente tendras un link a la ruta "home", si laravel no conoce la ruta, no puede generar el link.

Por eso, si la defines así:

```
Route::view('/', function (){
    return view('home');
});
```

Solo estás indicando cual template usar para renderizar, pero no le estás dando un nombre a la ruta.

Debes dárselo con la función `name` al igual que en el ejemplo inicial:

```
 Route::view('/', function (){
        return view('home');
    })->name("home");
```

Comment: Excelente Bro, me funciono en parte, adicionalemente cambie el Route::view por Route::get y me funciono, gracias :)